# Passing array of pointers to another class

Tags: c++, pointers, arrays

I am trying to do the following:

in main.cpp:

```
// Create an array of pointers to Block objects
Block *blk[64];
for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
  for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
    int x_low = i*80;
    int y_low = j*45;
    blk[j*8+i] = new Block(30, x_low+40.0f, y_low+7.5f, &b);
  }
}
```

And then I am trying to pass it to the graphics object I have created:

```
Graphics g(640, 480, &b, &p, blk[0], number_of_blocks);
```

the graphics constructor looks like:

```
Graphics::Graphics(int width, int height, Ball *b, Paddle *p, Block *blk, int number_of_blocks) {
```

if I look at what is contained in the array from the graphics object, only the first item exists and then all the other items are in hyperspace:

```
for (int i=0; i<64; i++) {
  printf("for block %d, %f, %f ", i, (_blk+(sizeof(_blk)*i))->_x_low, (_blk+(sizeof(_blk)*i))->_y_low);

  printf("blah %d\n", (_blk+(sizeof(_blk)*i)));

}
```

and if I look at the addresses, they are different (6956552 rather than 2280520 when I examine the addresses in the main  class using:

```
printf(" blah %d\n", &blk[j*8*i]);
```

I am sure there must be something subtle I am doing wrong as its like I have copied the first item from the blk array to a new address when passed to the graphics object.

Does this make sense?  Any ideas?

Cheers,
Scott

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass the whole array, the constructor should look like this:

```
Graphics::Graphics(int width, int height, Ball *b, Paddle *p,
    Block **blk, int number_of_blocks)
```

and you should pass the array like this:

```
Graphics g(640, 480, &b, &p, blk, number_of_blocks);
```

Comment: will this pass references to the array created in main or create a copy and pass a reference to that?

Comment: @user310153 Arrays are practically (almost) pointers, so `Block **blk` - a pointer to pointer to `Block` - as function parameter declaration, is equivalent to `Block *blk[]` - an array of pointers to `Block`. In other words, nothing is copied, the function accesses the contents of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

```
Graphics::Graphics(int width, int height, Ball *b, Paddle *p, Block *blk, int number_of_blocks) {
```

is expecting an array of Blocks, not an array of pointers to Blocks. Passing the first element would probably work if you made_number_of blocks 1, but it can't work for  anything else using your current data structure. If I were you, I would give up on using arrays and use std::vector instead - it will greatly simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `Graphics` function is expecting a contiguous array of `Block` objects in memory and you are creating each new `Block` independently.  Try

```
Block* blk = new Block[64];
```

then loop through and initialize each `Block`'s values.  This will only work if you can initialize the block objects in another way from using the constructor with arguments since `new` in this case can only call the default constructor.  If the only way to initialize a `Block` is using the constructor with arguments, you'll have to do something else like passing `Block**` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are passing the first element of the array to the contructor, not the whole array. This is what you are doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void foo(int* item, const int length);

int main() {
  const int length = 10;
  int* array[length];
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    array[i] = new int(i + 100);
  }
  foo(array[0], length);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void foo(int* item, const int length) {
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    std::cout << item[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I believe this is what you wanted to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void foo(int** array, const int length);

int main() {
  const int length = 10;
  int* array[length];
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    int* item = new int(i + 100);
    array[i] = item;
  }
  foo(array, length);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void foo(int** array, const int length) {
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    int* item = array[i];
    std::cout << *item << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Regards,
Rafael.